# How to access java native method from other project in flutter

Tags: java, android, flutter

I have 2 projects. One is main project and other is added as a library project.
following depedency is added in the main project.

```
dependencies:
  flutter:
sdk: flutter


library_project: 

path: D:\****\Flutter Projects\library-project
```

Now I can access any class and widget of library-project but
I have to access java native method in libarry project from main project.
Here is way how I am accessing native java from main to library project. following function is in library's class function, I accessed it from main project by importing function's class.

```
static const platform = const MethodChannel('example.flutter.io/test');
static Future<void>  testMehtod() async {
  try {
    final int result = await platform.invokeMethod("getBatteryLevel");
  } on PlatformException catch (e) {
    print(e.message);
  }   
}
```

here is Java native class

```
public class MainActivity extends FlutterActivity {
private static final String CHANNEL = "example.flutter.io/test";

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    GeneratedPluginRegistrant.registerWith(this);

    new MethodChannel(getFlutterView(), CHANNEL).setMethodCallHandler(
            new MethodCallHandler() {
                @Override
                public void onMethodCall(MethodCall call, Result result) {
                   if (call.method.equals("getBatteryLevel")) {
    int batteryLevel = getBatteryLevel();

    if (batteryLevel != -1) {
        result.success(batteryLevel);
    } else {
        result.error("UNAVAILABLE", "Battery level not available.", null);
    }
} else {
    result.notImplemented();
}
                }
            });
    }
}

private int getBatteryLevel() {
  int batteryLevel = -1;
  if (VERSION.SDK_INT >= VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
    BatteryManager batteryManager = (BatteryManager) getSystemService(BATTERY_SERVICE);
    batteryLevel = batteryManager.getIntProperty(BatteryManager.BATTERY_PROPERTY_CAPACITY);
  } else {
    Intent intent = new ContextWrapper(getApplicationContext()).
        registerReceiver(null, new IntentFilter(Intent.ACTION_BATTERY_CHANGED));
    batteryLevel = (intent.getIntExtra(BatteryManager.EXTRA_LEVEL, -1) * 100) /
        intent.getIntExtra(BatteryManager.EXTRA_SCALE, -1);
  }

  return batteryLevel;
}
```

**Here is exeption I am getting.**

> [ERROR:flutter/shell/common/shell.cc(186)] Dart Error: Unhandled exception:
>   E/flutter (25932): MissingPluginException(No implementation found for method testmethod on channel example.flutter.io/test)
>   E/flutter (25932): #0      MethodChannel.invokeMethod (package:flutter/src/services/platform_channel.dart:291:7)
>   E/flutter (25932): 
>   E/flutter (25932): #1      Utils.testMethod(package:library_project/utils/utils.dart:16:41)
>   E/flutter (25932): 
>   E/flutter (25932): #2      _MyHomePageState._incrementCounter. (package:arche_isp_dualmode/main.dart:60:13)

Comment: The `MainActivity` class lies in library is it???

Comment: @HemanthRaj yes its in library project

Comment: In that case, no, you cannot access it from main. Implement a platform channel in the library, then import the dart code of library and use it. That will work.